# SQL Update one table column based on another table column condition

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table:

```
mentor (mentor_id, name, contact, country)
team (team_id, mentor_id, name, status)
```

I want to update the `team.status = 'Approved' where team.mentor_id = mentor.mentor_id AND mentor.country = 'ABC';`

But above query is not working. Please assit me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` try this :-

```
update mentor m join
       team t
       on m.mentor_id = t.mentor_id
    set t.status = 'Approved' where m.country = 'ABC'
```